# How to organize menu items

Tags: android

I'm starting to learn Android stuff and I would like to know how I could organize/rearrange the different items in my menu on my Toolbar (for instance: how to push them to the center of my toolbar, how to decide how much space I want between the different items, etc..).

Right now, I have a menu_main.xml that looks like this :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <item
        android:id="@+id/miCompose"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_calendar"
        app:showAsAction="always"
        android:title="Calendar" >
    </item>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/miProfile"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_dining"
        app:showAsAction="always"
        android:title="Dining">
    </item>
</menu>
```

So that my items are displayed this way on my Toolbar:

http://zupimages.net/viewer.php?id=19/13/pr82.png

But I would like to find a way to get them to be at the center of my Toolbar.
Could someone help me, please? I can't seem to find anything right now...

Comment: What does your actual code look like?  What language are you using even?

Answer (score 0):

So Forget all  about menu.xml and Start thinking about Custom Menu items

You can add your individual Menu items Programmatically as well, like:

```
popup.getMenu().add(groupID,itemID,itemOrder,itemTitle);
```

'itemOrder' is Literally an Integer number for which order you want to add an item

For each Menu Item you need:

1. ID
2. Title
3. Icon (Optional)

So. Create a Class that gives you these characteristics, such as below:

```js
public class MyMenu {
    public static Integer Count(){
        return 4;
    }
    public static String title(int pick){
        String[] strings = new String[]{
                "title1",
                "title2",
                "title3",
                "title4"
        };

        return strings[pick];
    }
    public static int iconDrawable(int pick){
        int[] drawables = new int[]{
                R.drawable.icon1,
                R.drawable.icon2,
                R.drawable.icon3,
                R.drawable.icon4
        };

        return drawables[pick];
    }
}
```

Now Use this class to create your menu like this:

```js
PopupMenu popup = new PopupMenu(getActivity(), yourTargetView);
int count = MyMenu.Count();
for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
  popup.getMenu().add(1,
      i,
      i,
      MyMenu.title(i))
    .setIcon(MyMenu.iconDrawable(i))
    .setShowAsActionFlags(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_WITH_TEXT);
}
popup.setOnMenuItemClickListener(
  new PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
    public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
      // So Something on Click
      return true;
    }
  });
popup.show();
```

Now you can do whatever you want with such class. You can also use a Simple Arraylist for Titles or ID's or Orders

```
ArrayList<String> titles = new new ArrayList<>();
for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
  titles.add(_whatever);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer!

Answer (score 0):

toolbar is just view. you can use your custom view to work with childs without menu if you experiencing some troubles.

Or add  with custom layout as child